# Units of time in time analysis (frequency count method)

Tags: time-complexity

In time analysis, how many units of time will the piece of code
z=2x+3y;
 take?
 will it take 1 unit of rime or 4 units of time ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you measure "time". If it is in terms of "number of C sentences executed", it is just 1; if you want to measure "arithmetic operations computed" it is 3 (two multiplications, one addition); for "number of CPU instructions executed" you'd have to fix that one, translate and count; if "time" you'd need to do the above and see how much time it takes for your particular CPU (nowadays they are very complex beasts, the idea of "timing of one instruction, independent of it's environment" makes no sense for them as it did in eons past). If you want to count bit operations, it now depends on the exact values of $x$ and $y$.

In most (but not all!) algorithm complexity analyses you'll just say that the cost is some constant, $O(1)$ (more precisely, $\Theta(1)$), as you normally consider just machine precision (not e.g. very big integers, exact rationals, very high precission floating point numbers), and each operation is one (or some fixed number) of instructions taking a bounded time each.

For very important algorithms it is worthwhile to get more detailed timing results. But that gets *very* hairy real fast. For the ultimate in very detailed work, check out Donald Knuth's monumental series "The Art of Computer Programming". Definitely not for the faint of hearth. Sedgewick's "Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms" is somewhat of a middle ground.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on *CS*. It seems that the concept of temporal complexity of an algorithm is a little unclear to you. There is no thing like "*unity of time*". 
We are concerned with how the computation of a function (measured in number of operations of a *Turing Machine* and not in seconds or other time units) grows with increasing input.

In the case of your example the function is a sum, therefore it has constant complexity: $O(1)$.

Comment: It depends on how you measure "time". If it is in terms of "number of C senteces